# Rewards from Mutually Exclusive Factions in Morrowind?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

In The Elder Scrolls III:Morrowind, several of the player joinable factions are mutually exclusive, most notably, the three Great Houses of Telvaani, Redoran, and Hlaalu. While I'm familiar with the general bent of each (Telvaani are mages, Redoran warriors, Hlaalu thieves), and I know the general recommendation is "When in Doubt, Choose Telvaani," because the rewards are generally considered superior, and Telvaani is the basis for some excellent mod content as well.

What I'm curious about though is if there's a single listing somewhere comparing the rewards of the three paths against each other, to allow for a choice based on the rewards, rather than the skills involved. [The Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/) sadly doesn't consolidate this info, though it has a listing of all the quests for each faction, the rewards are not broken out, so finding them requires a lot of digging. Is there a better resource?

Again, to be clear, I'm specifically interested in **only a listing of rewards which are unique or rare items** (not gold or soul gems or rep or other things available in abundance elsewhere), *which are exclusive* to one faction which restricts your ability to join others. The current answers to this question provide a listing of which exclusive factions exist, and of the non-unique rewards for one of these factions. Neither of these is what I am asking for.

Comment: Are you only interested in items? I played House Redoran, and thought the stronghold they gave me was really cool... But then, I never saw the Telvaani's wizard tower.

Comment: @Izzy all three reward a stronghold. Unless there is some *unique* gameplay feature involved, I'm not interested.

Comment: If you are only interested in the three Great Houses, perhaps changing the question title would make it clearer - "Rewards from Great House Faction Quests in Morrowind" or something. As it stands, it seems to be asking about the rewards from every single faction with their diverse mutual exclusivity combinations which of course is too broad to answer here.

Comment: @skovacs the only other case of mutual exclusivity is the vampire clans, which I'm interested in as well.

Comment: I've added the vampire clans to my answer. If you wanted those, you should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**No. There is no single list that compiles it all, but I'll do my best to make you one.**

Thankfully you are only concerned with "the three Great Houses of Telvaani, Redoran, and Hlaalu" and Vampire Clans as typing up the full list for every faction in the game exceeds the character limit for answers. There are thankfully only 95 Great House quests and 6 Vampire quests.

I typed up all quests and rewards as "rare" could apply to many of the magical items, scrolls and skill books. As quest items are technically unique as there is usually only one of each them, I noted(#) these where applicable. Unique Items are also noted(*). Artifacts are noted(!) a well. Only items exclusively available to the quest or that are needed for the quest have been noted. For reference, he wiki's [Unique Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Armor), [Unique Weapons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Weapons), [Unique Clothing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing), [Quest Items](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items), [Weapon Artifacts](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Weapon_Artifacts), [Armor Artifacts](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Armor_Artifacts), and [Clothing Artifacts](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Clothing_Artifacts) pages were referred to and are as close as you are likely to get to a single list of awesome stuff.

```
* preceded quests can be accessed outside of the faction
*Unique Item*   #Quest Item#    !Artifact!
  Quest                                     Reward
```

---

```
Hlaalu
  Stronghold                                Stronghold
  Disguise                                  500 gold and #Native Gah-Julan Bonemold Helm#
  Alchemical Formulas                       None
  Inanius Egg Mine                          500 gold or 1000 gold or 1500 gold
  Guar Hide Squeeze                         1000 gold
  Delivery for Bivale Teneran               500 gold and Extravagant Pants and Exquisite Shirt
* The Death of Ralen Hlaalo                 1000 gold
  Epony Trade                               1000 gold and Glass Boots and Glass Greaves and Glass Cuirass
* Bank Courier                              50 gold
* Murudius Flaeus's Debt                    543 gold
  Escort Tarvyn Faren                       500 gold
  Telvanni at Odirniran                     500 gold or 1000 gold
  Exterminator                              1 gold or 1000 gold
  Ashlander Ebony                           1000 gold
  The Shipwreck 'Prelude'                   500 gold (#Daedric Wakizashi# is turned in)
  Guard Ralen Tilvur                        1000 gold
  An Admiring Sponsor                       Sponsorship
  Sealed Orders                             100 or 500 gold
  The Caldera Spy                           500 gold or 1000 gold or 1000 gold and 2 Scroll of Golnara's Eye-Maze and 2 Scroll of The Fourth Barrier
  Erroneous Documents                       *Amulet of Domination* or Murdrum Ring or 2 Scroll of Uth's Hand of Heaven and 2 Scroll of The Black Storm and 2 Scroll of Tranasa's Spelltwist
  Rent and Taxes                            -100 gold or None or 100 gold or 400 gold or 500 gold
  Shipment of Ebony                         500 gold or Dire Shardbolt Ring
  Velfred the Outlaw                        500 gold or 1000 gold
  Kill Banden Indarys                       1000 gold
  Bero's Support                            None
  Kill Reynel Uvirith                       1000 gold
  Literacy Campaign                         None
* The Twin Lamps                            None
* Free Hides-His-Foot                       None
  Control the Ordinators                    None (#Robe of St Roris# turned in)
  Dealing with Orvas Dren                   Promotion to Grandmaster in the Hlaalu faction
Redoran
  Stronghold                                Stronghold
* Mudcrab Pests                             2 Hackle-Lo Leaf
  Deliver Cure Disease Potion               None
  Founder's Helm                            None (#Redoran Founder's Helm# is turned in)
* Trouble with Bandits                      2 Hackle-Lo Leaf
  Guard Sarethi Manor                       200 gold
  Old Blue Fin                              10 Dreugh Wax
  Ashimanu Mine                             None
  Kagouti Den                               None
  Shishi Report                             None
  Kill Gordol                               *Enchanted Ebony Spear*
  Rescue Varvur Sarethi                     Promotion in the Redoran faction
  Clear Varvur Sarethi's Name               None (#Suspicious Ash Statue# is turned in)
  Ondres Nerano's Slanders                  None
  Shurinbaal                                None
  The Mad Lord of Milk                      Ebony Closed Helm (#Delyna's Locket# is turned in)
  Duel with Bolvyn Venim                    Promotion to Archmaster in the Redoran faction
  Ash Statue                                4 Quality Restore Health Potions and 1 Cure Blight Disease Potion and 1 Cure Common Disease Potion
  Find Fedris Tharen                        1 Cure Common Disease Potions or 4 Cure Common Disease Potions
* Find Beden Giladren                       None
  Recover Shields from Andasreth            #Redoran Banner Shield#
  Mission to Morvayn Manor                  Amulet of Mighty Blows (#Morvayn Ash Statue# is turned in)
  Evidence of Corruption                    None
  Shut the Mines Down                       Ebony Boots
  Taxes from Gnisis                         None
  Nalvilie Saren                            None
  Miner Arobar's Support                    *Arobar's Amulet* and Redoran Master Helm
* Meril Hlaano's Slanders                   Holy Shield
  Redas Tomb                                None (#Redas War Axe# and #Redas Robe of Deeds# and #Redas Goblet# are turned in, but will be given back once promoted to Archmaster)
  Duel of Honor                             None
  Slay Dagoth Tanis                         Ancestor's Ring (#Nervion Ancestor Ring# is turned in)
  Slay Reynel Uvirith                       None
  Slay Raynasa Rethan                       None
  Escort to Koal Cave                       Steel Firesword
  Armor Repair Debts                        Glass Frostsword
Telvanni
  Stronghold                                Stronghold
  Muck                                      Cure Common Disease Spell
  Black Jinx                                Demoralize Humanoid Spell and Demoralize Creature Spell (#Black Jinx# is turned in)
  Sload Soap                                250 gold or 500 gold
  Staff of the Silver Dawn                  Glass Jinkblade and Blind Spell (*Silver Staff* is turned in)
  New Clothes                               500 gold and Mark Spell and Recall Spell (#Therana's Skirt# is turned in)
  Slave Rebellion                           Firestorm Ring and/or Toxic Cloud Ring or Command Creature Spell and Command Humanoid Spell
  Dwemer Books                              *Ondusi's Key* and *Amulet of Admonition* and Second Barrier Belt and *Surefeet*
  Dahrk Mezalf                              Dwemer Shock Centurion Guard and Ring of Lightning Storm
  Three Questions for Baladas Demnevanni    None or 3 Messenger Scrolls
  Mission to Nchuleft                       *Gothren's Cephalopod Helm*
  Coded Message                             500 gold (you get 7 Healing Potions and 4 Water Walking Potions and 4 Swift Swim Potions that you may need to use)
  Cure Blight                               500 gold
  Daedra Skin                               300 gold and Paralysis Spell
  Auriel's Bow                              *Daedric Cuirass* and *Daedric Greaves* or 11,111 gold (!Auriel's Bow! is turned in)
  Flesh Made Whole                          Amulet of Spell Absorption and 4 Summon Golden Saint Scrolls (Female only) (*Amulet of Flesh Made Whole* is turned in)
  Drake's Pride                             10 gold (#Robe of the Drake's Pride# is turned in)
  Baladas Demnevanni                        Silver Staff of Peace and Promotion to Aryon's Mouth in the Telvanni faction
  Mudan-Mul Egg Mine                        Alteration Skill Book
  Wizard Spells                             Destruction Skill Book
  Odirniran                                 7 Milyn Faram's Scrolls and *Silver Staff of Hunger* and Illusion Skill Book
  Mages Guild Monopoly                      *Aryon's Dominator*
  Shishi                                    Alteration Skill Book and Destruction Skill Book and Silver Staff of War
  Recruit a Mouth                           *Aryon's Helper* and Promotion to Wizard in the Telvanni faction
  Kill Raynasa Rethan                       None
  Kill Banden Indarys                       None
  Archmagister Gothren                      Promotion to Archmagister
  Ring of Equity                            *Ring of Equity*
  Amulet of Unity                           *Amulet of Unity*
Aundae
  Blood Ties                                Services in Ashmelech and #Aundae Signet Ring# (#Sinyaramen's Potion# is turned in, but you can get infinite amounts wearing the ring)
  The Vampire Hunter                        *Aundae Amulet* and *Light of Day* (as loot when not vampire) and *Darksun Shield* (as loot) and access to Aundae cattle
Berne
  The Blood of the Quarra                   Services in Galom Daeus (#Blood of the Quarra Masters# is turned in)
  The Vampire Merta                         *Berne Amulet* and access to Berne cattle
Quarra
  The Cult of Lord Irarak                   1000 gold and Services in Druscashti
  The Quarra Amulet                         *Quarra Amulet* and access to Quarra cattle
```

Noteworthy items from the three Great Houses:

- Hlaalu quests can be rewarded with #[Native Gah-Julan Bonemold Helm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Native_Gah-Julan_Bonemold_Helm)# and *[Amulet of Domination](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Amulet_of_Domination)*.
- Hlaalu quests turn in #[Daedric Wakizashi](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Daedric_Wakizashi)# and #[Robe of St Roris](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Robe_of_St_Roris)#.
- Redoran quests can be rewarded with *[Enchanted Ebony Spear](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Weapons#Ebony_Spear)*, #[Redoran Banner Shield](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redoran_Banner_Shield)# and *[Arobar's Amulet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Arobar.27s_Amulet)*.
- Redoran quests turn in #[Redoran Founder's Helm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redoran_Founder.27s_Helm)#, #[Suspicious Ash Statue](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Suspicious_Ash_Statue)#, #[Delyna's Locket](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Delyna.27s_Locket)#, #[Morvayn Ash Statue](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Morvayn_Ash_Statue)#, #[Redas War Axe](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redas_War_Axe)#, #[Redas Robe of Deeds](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redas_Robe_of_Deeds)#, #[Redas Goblet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redas_Goblet)# and #[Nervion Ancestor Ring](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Nervion_Ancestor_Ring)#.
- Redoran Archmaster can get back #[Redas War Axe](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redas_War_Axe)#, #[Redas Robe of Deeds](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redas_Robe_of_Deeds)# and #[Redas Goblet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Redas_Goblet)#
- Telvanni quests can be rewarded with *[Ondusi's Key](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Ondusi.27s_Key)*, *[Amulet of Admonition](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Amulet_of_Admonition)*, *[Surefeet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Surefeet)*, *[Gothren's Cephalopod Helm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind%3aUnique_Armor#Gothren.27s_Cephalopod_Helm)*, *[Daedric Cuirass](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind%3aUnique_Armor#Daedric_Cuirass)*, *[Daedric Greaves](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind%3aUnique_Armor#Daedric_Greaves)*, *[Silver Staff of Hunger](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind%3aUnique_Weapons#Silver_Staff_of_Hunger)*, *[Aryon's Dominator](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Aryon.27s_Dominator)*, *[Aryon's Helper](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Aryon.27s_Helper)*, *[Ring of Equity](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Ring_of_Equity)* and *[Amulet of Unity](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Amulet_of_Unity)*.
- Telvanni quests turn in #[Black Jinx](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Black_Jinx)#, *[Silver Staff](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Weapons#Silver_Staff)*, #[Therana's Skirt](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Therana.27s_Skirt)#, ![Auriel's Bow](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind%3aWeapon_Artifacts#Auriel.27s_Bow)!, *[Amulet of Flesh Made Whole](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Amulet_of_Flesh_Made_Whole)* and #[Robe of the Drake's Pride](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Robe_of_the_Drake.27s_Pride)#.

Noteworthy items from the Vampire Clans:

- Aundae quests can be rewarded with #[Aundae Signet Ring](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Aundae_Signet_Ring)#, *[Aundae Amulet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Aundae_Amulet)*, *[Light of Day](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind%3aUnique_Weapons#Light_of_Day)* (as loot *when not vampire*) and *[Darksun Shield](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind%3aUnique_Armor#Darksun_Shield)* (as loot).
- Aundae quests turn in #[Sinyaramen's Potion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Potions#Sinyaramen.27s_Potion)#, but with the #[Aundae Signet Ring](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Items#Aundae_Signet_Ring)# you can continue to get an infinite amount of them.
- Berne quests can be rewarded with *[Berne Amulet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Berne_Amulet)*.
- Berne quests turn in #[Blood of the Quarra Masters](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Potions#Blood_of_the_Quarra_Masters)#.
- Quarra quests can be rewarded with *[Quarra Amulet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Unique_Clothing#Quarra_Amulet)*.

Comment: Thanks for the *enormous* effort. I'm going to go through and clean this up, prune out the items that are unique, rare, or potent for when you can get them in terms of function when I get the chance, but this is already a huge help. :)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz No problem. I'll be adding the links to the relevant wiki entries in a bit to hopefully make it a bit easier. It's tough to judge "rarity" and "quality" as they really depend on how you play. That's why I picked out the noteworthy Quest Items(#) and Unique Items(*) and Artifact(!).

Answer (score 9):

What you ask for is difficult to pin down because there is a lot of variation based on player choice. For example here's a quick and dirty chart I came up with just for House Hlaalu. Note: the values listed are the maximum values (assuming the wiki is accurate) you can earn for completing that quest. Many quests award multiple items. The values listed are the sum of all the monetary value of the items you'd receive.

```
Quest                        Gold  Item(s)  Faction Rep  World Rep
Disguise                     500   150      5
Alchemical Formulas                         5
Egg Mine                     1500           10
Guar Hide Squeeze            1000           5
Delivery for Bivale Teneran  500   180      5
The Death of Ralen Hlaalo    1000           10           1
Epony Trade                  1000  53600    10           2
Bank Courier                 50             5
Murudius Flaeus's Debt       543
Escort Tarvyn Faren          500            5   
Telvanni at Odirniran        1000           10           1
Exterminator                 1000           10
Ashlander Ebony              1000           5            1
The Shipwreck 'Prelude'      500
Guard Ralen Tilvur           1000           5            1
An Admiring Sponsor
Sealed Orders                500            5
The Caldera Spy              1000   580     10           1
Erroneous Documents                 2332    5
Rent and Taxes               400            5            1
Shipment of Ebony            500    79
Velfred the Outlaw           1000
Kill Banden Indarys          1000           10           1
Bero's Support                              15
Kill Reynel Uvirith          1000           10           1
Literacy Campaign                           5
The Twin Lamps                              5            1
Free Hides-His-Foot                         5            1
Control the Ordinators                      10           8
Dealing with Orvas Dren                                  1
Stronghold                                               1
Totals                       16493  56921   175          22
```

Comment: Yep, I'm specifically looking for unique item rewards, but this Hlallu listing is a start!

Answer (score 5):

So I did a little digging and I found this table:

[image]

made more helpful by this key:

[image]

and finally, this formula:

`Disposition Adjustment = (Reaction * fDispFactionMod ) * (fDispFactionRankBase + (FactionRank *fDispFactionRankMult))`

Now, I'm told you can only join one of the three great houses (at least without [the uses of bugs](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Redoran_or_Telvanni_and_Hlaalu)), and you can join both Thieves and Fighters Guilds (though it takes some work) and neither have problems with the mage guild.  You can't join the temple once you become Nerevarine, but that's not really related.  I think you only join one vampire clan, but I don't have a source for that one.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It's a handy table, that's for sure, but it kinda bypasses what I'm looking for. You're dead on about which houses are mutually exclusive (One Vampire Clan, One Great House, Thieves + Fighters if you're not careful) -  my main concern has more to do with the unique quest rewards available from those exclusive factions, not their interactions.

Comment: @Less I'm sorry I miss read your question

Answer (score 0):

As far as item rewards go, Telvanni is by far superior. The only reason not to go telvanni would be if you didn't want your home to be a mushroom tower.

You get glass weapons, dwarven crossbows, enchanted jewelry, as well as an enchanted helmet that lets you conjure a dremora lord and daedric chest and leg armor enchanted with 50 points of feather each. Telvanni is not interested in the affairs of other organizations and are also the most powerful house. Their lords are not concerned with money or even other members of the house.

Redoran and Hlaalu are both relatively bland organizations worried about territorial claims and political infighting. Although some Hlaalu house members are funny, that is about the extent of the character in those houses.